# Node.js shows [object Object] instead of result.row

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm using postgresql version 11 and have a user with id=3 with a post field(text type). when I want to show the post from database it shows [object Object] instead of the post with id=3

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { Pool, Client } = require('pg')
const connectionString = 'postgresql://postgres:1111@localhost:5432/netSecure'


const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: connectionString,
})

app.get('/h', (req, res) => {
    pool.query('SELECT post from users where id=3', (err, result) => {
        if(err) return console.log('error in query',err);
        console.log(result.rows);
        res.render('posts.pug', {
            post: result.rows
        });
        res.end();
    });
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('http://localhost:3000'))
```

pug file with #{post}:

```
  body
    form(action='/posts',method='post')
        label(for='exampleFormControlTextarea1') Enter Your Post
        textarea(autofocus='', placeholder='Post your message here...')#exampleFormControlTextarea1.form-control(rows='3')
        button(type="button").send Send
    form(action='/logout',method='post')
        button.logout Logout
    p #{post}
```

Where did I make mistake?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Hossein! What do you mean by "show the post from the database?" If the `console.log(result.rows);` part is what you are referring to, what happens if you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(result.rows));`?

Comment: thanks @Pytth console.log(result.rows); shows : [ { post: 'Hello this is a post' } ] but in the pug page I see nothing but [object Object]. as you said I used JSON.stringify(result.rows)) instead of result.rows and it works.tnk u!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[object Object]` is the default toString representation of an object in javascript.

It seems that you only want to retrieve one post with id = 3. So first you need to extract one result because postgresql will give you an array of result no matter what.

And then, you need to process the JSON object so that it is not shown as `[object Object]`. For quick solution, you can use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

So here is the snippet of your code

```
app.get('/h', (req, res) => {
    pool.query('SELECT post from users where id=3', (err, result) => {
        if(err) return console.log('error in query',err);
        // need to check if post exists
        let post = (result.rows.length > 0) ? result.rows[0] : null;
        let postInString = JSON.stringify(post);
        console.log(postInString);
        res.render('posts.pug', {
            post: postInString,
        });
        res.end();
    });
```

Comment: thanks it works! but it shows the data in the json format how can I use it raw and clear with no "[]" or "{}"  ??

Comment: Happy to help!. Sorry but what you mean by "raw and clear"? Symbol [] and {} are part of JSON and cannot be eliminated. If you really want it, you need to manually control the display. For example you can manually display each property:
console.log('Post title: ' + post.title);
console.log('Post content: ' + post.content);
and so on..

Comment: I want it to be as a plain text with no brackets I searched and saw a replace function like:           `postInString.replace('{', '');` to remove the "{" but it does not work,Am I missing something?

Comment: I see. replace() should work. However, replace() is a pure function, which means it doesn't modify the data, instead it returns the new result. So what you need to do is store the result `postInString = postInString.replace('{', '')`

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you are trying to `console.log` something that is not in string format; this is why you are seeing `[Object object]`.

To log what you actually want, consider first turning the object into a string with `JSON.stringify(result.rows)`.